# JQuery data grid with form view edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have been looking around at several Data Grids for JQuery UI.

I have found several such as:

```
* Flexigrid: http://flexigrid.info/
* jQuery Grid: http://www.trirand.com/blog/
* jqGridView: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqGridView
* Ingrid: http://reconstrukt.com/ingrid/
* SlickGrid http://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid
```

However, what I need to do is when a record is clicked, expand the record into a sort of in-line form for the user to enter information. The amount of information in this form is much greater than the amount show in each gridview row.

For example you might see:

```
Header
Row 1
Row 2
Row 3
Row 4
Row 5
```

then click on Row 3 and see

```
Header
Row 1
Row 2
Form
Data input..... input and change data about the item that was in Row 3
Some more data input from input fields, selects etc.
End Form
Row4
Row5
```

Any ideas on how to use one of these data grid addons or another addon?

Or another way to go about doing this all together?

Thanks!

P.S. I would like it to look as professional as possible :)

Comment: ugh... nothing? I still have come up empty handed with every google search...

Comment: well i'm going to go with this idea. i have a div with a button and a div in it. then I give each a class and add this click function to every button with that class: `$(this).parents(".myTestDiv").chilren(".myTableDiv").append("#myTable")` where myTable is the form that you want to show inline, and each table element has this div with a div and a button in it. i'll post a solution when I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://jeasyui.com

They have, buried deep within the demos, an example of what you describe. I could not find it on their website, but I have implemented an in table edit (that expands to a larger form just below the table item).

Comment: I guess I should have checked the date of this request first.

The components at http://jeasyui.com will definitely do what you ask, but it is not opensource. Sorry for the confusion and late edits.

Comment: It's ok. Helped me out a lot. what you describe is located at http://jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php .. click on left text link called "Expand Row Form".